# Mule - DataMapper throws "Error while validating DB connection."

Tags: mule

```
...org.jetel.connection.jdbc.DBConnection: Error while validating DB connection.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jetel.connection.jdbc.DBConnection.isValid(DBConnection.java:531)
    at org.jetel.connection.jdbc.DBConnection.getConnection(DBConnection.java:473)
    at org.jetel.lookup.DBLookupTable.preExecute(DBLookupTable.java:188)
    at org.jetel.graph.TransformationGraph.preExecute(TransformationGraph.java:526)
    at com.mulesoft.mule.module.datamapper...
```

Above is the error that I'm seeing in my MuleStudio console; however, according to datamapper DB lookup validation function (see image below), the DB connection seems fine.

[image]

**Question:** what is causing this error & how to fix this error?

Comment: I am having the same issue in MySQL. Any luck finding a solution?

Comment: I wrote to Mule for support on this matter. They will look into it.

Comment: It looks like the new Anypoint Studio does not have this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the new Anypoint Studio does not have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me it fixed when I add the mysql jar path in the project build path selecting the 'add external jar' option.

Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Libraries -> Ass External Jars.